# Reload javascript on Postback of razor page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a razor page and on postback if the model state is invalid the jQuery validation will fire.

Now I have a custom function or a .js file that I need to either reload or fire 1 function on a postback, how to do it?

Not able to find a straight answers as most of them say that a server side code is required to fire it. Please suggest.

How to call "callFN();" on a postback.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</head>

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="AppUser.Id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="pageRet" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input asp-for="user.FName" class="form-control required" />
        <span asp-validation-for="user.FName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
        <input asp-for="user.LName" class="form-control required" />
        <span asp-validation-for="user.LName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    function callFN() {
        alert("My Call");
    }

    //called on page load, but how to call this on postback
    callFN();
});
</script>
```

As requested here is the controller code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class EditUserModel : PageModel
{
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

[BindProperty]
public string pageRet { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public List<HostelUserHistory> huHistory { get; set; }

public EditUserModel(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
{
    _context = context;
    _userManager = userManager;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
{
    huHistory = new List<UserHistory>();
    pageRet = HttpContext.Request.Query["ret"].ToString();
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    huHistory = await _context.UserHistory
                .Where(h => h.AppUserId == AppUser.Id)
                .ToListAsync();
    ViewData["huHistory"] = huHistory;

    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    //do some other thing
    return Redirect(pageRet);
}

}
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Your script will be be called when you return the view.

Comment: Yes it should but i am not returning view like return view(); but i am using asp.net core return page(); and after that the script is not called

Comment: Then tag you question correctly :) - and I suggest you show the controller code to make it clear)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the controller code and marked it in correct catagory.

Comment: Return Page is the equivalent to Return View. You should check the browser's development tools (F12) to see if there are any errors reported in the console when the page is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today and was scratching my head until I found a solution that worked for me.

First off, my problem is exactly the same as your's, except in my controller method I was returning a PartialView. I had a js function in a `$(document).ready()` block that would run on initial load, but not after an invalid form submit.

What finally worked for me was putting a `<script>` tag within the `<form>` itself. For example, the fix to your problem would be:

```
<form method="post">
    ...HTML FORM ELEMENTS...

    <script>$(document).ready(function (){callFN();});</script>
</form>
```

For some reason it seems that when returning a view from a form submit method, JavaScript on the initial page isn't run again, and any code that performs dynamic styling or data creation on DOM load has issues. I'm not sure if this is the case, but I've been digging around trying to figure out WHY this works the way it does. Anyone do please reply to this if you have more insight.